# android sd card path for all devices

Tags: android

I tried to get sd card path to store image using this code:

```
String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

But it didnot work for all devices and all versions of android.

Comment: [External storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) is generally not [removable storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded to do it using this code:

```
public File getSDPath() {
    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath();

    if (android.os.Build.DEVICE.contains("samsung")
            || android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER.contains("samsung")) {
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getParent() + "/extSdCard");
        if (f.exists() && f.isDirectory()) {
            try {
                File file = new File(f, "test");
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .getParent() + "/extSdCard";
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            }

        } else {
            f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsolutePath() + "/external_sd");
            if (f.exists() && f.isDirectory()) {
                try {
                    File file = new File(f, "test");
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            .getAbsolutePath() + "/external_sd";
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                }

            }
        }
    }

    return new File(filepath);
}
```

Comment: This will not work for all devices, for example on my Chinese phone, the removable SD card is at `/mnt/extsd/`

Comment: That is right, but I don't have better solution. If somebody can help us, I'll be Thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String sdcardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
```

Comment: The same problem occurs on some galaxy phones